# How to make shortcut to terminal application?

Tags: command-line, icons

I just installed a nifty calculator tool that needs to run from a terminal: `tapecalc`

Is there a way to add either a shortcut icon (or an icon in the dash application area) or a short cut key combination so I can run this without opening a terminal and then remembering what the app's name is and then entering tapecalc in the terminal window to start it?

Answer (score 7):

Create a FileName.desktop with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/path-to-you-app/application_name
Terminal=true
```

Comment: The user needs to be able to interact with the application. Doesn't this require that the application be run in a Terminal app (with a line like `Exec="gnome-terminal -e /usr/bin/tapecalc"`)?

Comment: _Terminal field specifies whether the application should run in a terminal window or not._ [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Comment: Not working for me. I've created "julia.desktop" (placed it in Desktop folder), with contents: "[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.3.0-prerelease
Name=Julia
Comment="start Julia through IJulia"
Exec=gnome-terminal ipython notebook --profile julia
Terminal=true, with newlines as shown above. When I double-click on the file, I get "There was an error launching the application." From the terminal, "ipython notebook --profile julia" works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start the Terminal and make it run the command automatically. Create a [custom application launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToAddaLauncher) that runs this as the *command*:

```
gnome-terminal -e tapecalc
```

While this is a perfectly good way to do it, [pl1nk](https://askubuntu.com/users/48864/pl1nk)'s [way](https://askubuntu.com/a/143926/22949) is even better (in part because it will run with whatever terminal application is set as default in your desktop environment). Since that was posted, I now recommend using that method instead of this, and upvoting [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/143926/22949). **:-)**